# Using C# to send fax from real fax machine, connected to the computer

Tags: c#, .net, fax

I would like to send fax message from my C# application. But I don't want to send "internet fax". I want to send fax from real fax machine.

Currently I don't have fax machine, but I will have a moment for test on my friend's machine. So I'm looking for an example (with C#, .NET4) or some clues. I've got Windows 7. But it will be good if it works also on Vista and XP.

Thanks in advance,

UPDATE: 
I want to write a C#-app, which will be sending faxes from that real fax machine. (Like sms from mobile phone connected to the computer).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you are using XP, but take a look at [Faxing with XP and C#](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/Fax-XP-ing.aspx).

Comment: Thanks, I will try that tomorrow, but It's from 2004 and has only 2 stars. I'm not sure if that is good solution.

Answer (score 0):

Try out [GFI Faxmaker](http://www.gfi.com/faxmaker). You will be able to to XML API to create fax commands

Comment: Like I said: "But I don't want to send "internet fax". I want to send fax from real fax machine."